# Concave hull error: not enough arguments

Tags: qgis, typeerror, concave-hull

I am trying to run concave hull on a points layer, but I keep running into this error:

> TypeError: translate(str, str, disambiguation: str = None, n: int =
>   -1): not enough arguments

What am I doing wrong?

I'm using QGIS 3.0.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade to QGIS 3.2 - it's been fixed in that version